# Lost commit history for a branch in octopus merge

Tags: git, version-control, merge

I just lost the local commits on a branch after an (accidental) octopus merge but don't understand why.
Here is the reflog:

```
8191469 HEAD@{0}: checkout: moving from develop to feature
832315f HEAD@{1}: checkout: moving from feature to develop
8191469 HEAD@{2}: merge develop: Merge made by the 'recursive' strategy.
e17facc HEAD@{3}: checkout: moving from develop to feature
832315f HEAD@{4}: pull: Fast-forward
fe8ddbb HEAD@{5}: checkout: moving from feature to develop
e17facc HEAD@{6}: commit: B.
4a3d1b7 HEAD@{7}: reset: moving to 4a3d1b79f15981e36fe20079acb7e376ff9a771d
b1635a3 HEAD@{8}: reset: moving to b1635a3a047a0eb0a0e71b7adc9348f6d3837359
9497ed9 HEAD@{9}: merge develop: Merge made by the 'recursive' strategy.
b1635a3 HEAD@{10}: commit (merge): Merge commit '4a3d1b79f15981e36fe20079acb7e376ff9a771d' into feature
ced6980 HEAD@{11}: merge e4403818b8296a2b0aa1e7bd46f59c809b0977b6: Merge made by the 'recursive' strategy.
da7a4bb HEAD@{12}: checkout: moving from develop to feature
fe8ddbb HEAD@{13}: pull origin develop: Fast-forward
2b639b0 HEAD@{14}: checkout: moving from feature to develop
da7a4bb HEAD@{15}: reset: moving to da7a4bb2fa71f327275ab82cd03e437f67ac4561
e806af4 HEAD@{16}: merge develop e4403818b8296a2b0aa1e7bd46f59c809b0977b6: Merge made by the 'octopus' strategy.
da7a4bb HEAD@{17}: commit: Older missing commits go on from here
                   .
                   .
                   .
```

The fix for this was [here](http://eclipsesource.com/blogs/2011/05/29/life-lesson-be-mindful-of-a-detached-head/)
All I needed to do was

```
git reflog
```

find the right commit before the merge in

```
git reset --hard <sha1 of that commit>
```

Why does the octopus merge remove the parent node of the branch?

Answer (score 0):

Did you push before pulling develop?

da7a4bb HEAD@{15}: reset: moving to da7a4bb2fa71f327275ab82cd03e437f67ac4561

you did reset here and right after that you did

e806af4 HEAD@{16}: merge develop e4403818b8296a2b0aa1e7bd46f59c809b0977b6: Merge made by the 'octopus' strategy.

develop merge which sealed top of the branch...

If you did push it could be helpfull to reset to commit right before the merge off develop with (on the feature):

```
   git reset --hard <sha of commit before oct merge>
```

after that you should be able to get what you lost with git pull

if you did not push than your data might be lost but try this:

When at the point before octo merge, use this command to find your lost commits:

```
   git fsck --lost-found
```

Also you can use reflog again at this point to see lost commits

If git knows about commits that you have lost use

```
   git merge <sha of the lost commit git found for you>
```

To recover your precious data

Comment: But why does the octopus merge seal the top of the branch? Shouldn't it keep the parent node anyway?

Comment: I based my answer on diagnose I made from your log... I can not make out what exacly you did to cause double reset that appears there...

Final idea would be that octopus merge which is alogithm to solve merge with multiple heads when you do not want manual conflict resolution, went into a buggy (corner?) case and resolved conflicts merging heads and leaving only one branch...

You could find your answer by reading through Git docs to see how octopus strategy works under the hood... I personally insist on manual conflict resolution by developers that work on the code.

Comment: The restoring to a reflog point solved it ( I put it on the question).

Comment: "If you did push it could be helpfull to reset to commit right before the merge off develop ..." You don't need to push. The commit will still be there on your computer. Although it might be hard to find if you didn't have the foresight to make a note of the commit id before you started.